# dynamic colspan

Tags: php, html

I have a table will show data from a database. These data count is `dynamic`. I want to show 4 in each row. However, the problem with the last row. I want if the last row has 1 TD the function will give this td a `colspan` of 4, so I can show the data in the middle.

```
NUMBER OF DATA IS 5

###############################################
#           TABLE HEADER(colspan=4)           #
###############################################
||  TD1   ||  TD2  ||   TD3   ||    TD4     ||
||  TD5   ||  

I NEED THIS 
###############################################
#           TABLE HEADER(colspan=4)           #
###############################################
||  TD1   ||  TD2  ||   TD3   ||    TD4     ||
||                  TD5                     ||  

and if there are 6 TDS to show it like this.

###############################################
#           TABLE HEADER(colspan=4)           #
###############################################
||  TD1   ||  TD2  ||   TD3   ||    TD4     ||
||       TD5       ||          TD6          ||
```

MY PHP CODE + HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">TABLE HEADER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <? $counter = 0;
                foreach($data as $d)
                {
                    if($counter % 4 == 0)
                    {
                        echo '</tr><tr>';
                    }
                    echo $d['name'];
                    $counter++
                }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: And what if there are 7 records you want to show..??

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal 3 TDS each td has a width = 33%

Comment: Well, given your last comment, try my 2nd example (where you put a new table in the last column - which is the easiest way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get your started. It is probably not the most elegant, but it will do.

```
<tr>
    <? $counter = 0;
       $lastrow = floor($count($data)/4)*4;
       $numinlastrow = $count($data)%4;
            foreach($data as $d)
            {
                if($counter % 4 == 0)
                {
                    echo '</tr><tr>';
                }
                $colspan = 1;
                if ($counter >= $lastrow) {
                  if ($numinlastrow == 1) $colspan = 4;
                  if ($numinlastrow == 2) $colspan = 2;
                  if ($numinlastrow == 3) ; // ??
                }
                echo "<td colspan='".$colspan."'>";
                //... contents of table cell here
                echo "</td>";
                $counter++
            }
    ?>
</tr>
```

If there are 3 table cells, it isn't really possible with the method above, because `colspan` can only span whole table columns (no fractions).

So, instead, put a table inside a table cell spanning the whole row...

```
<tr>
    <? $counter = 0;
       $lastrow = floor($count($data)/4)*4;
       $numinlastrow = $count($data)%4;
            foreach($data as $d)
            {
                if($counter % 4 == 0)
                {
                  if ($counter >= $lastrow) {
                    echo '</tr><tr><td colspan="4"><table><tr>';
                  }
                  else echo '</tr><tr>';
                }

                echo "<td>";
                //... contents of table cell here
                echo "</td>";
                $counter++
            }
            if ($numinlastrow != 0) echo '</tr></table></td>'
    ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the following way (approximately)--although this may look a little silly, but I can't think of a better way at the moment:

```
$num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < ($num_of_rows / 4); $i++)
{
   for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++)
   {
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      echo $row['name'];
   }
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 3)
{
   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo '<td colspan="2">'.$row['name'].'</td>';
   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
   mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
}
else
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      echo '<td colspan="'.(4 / mysql_num_rows($result)).'">'.$row['name'].'</td>';
   }
}
```